# JavaScript needed in determining seconds elapsed in current year starting Jan 01 at 00:00

Tags: javascript, gettime

I am newbee in JavaScript and i am having toughtime calculating seconds elapsed in current year not from 1970 as JavaScript default method calculates. 
Basically i need to develop script which will show countup timer of products produced in current year. Question is a company produces 4 million product in a year and i need to show Counter which will show current number of items produced and keep on counting up as long as i am on this counter page. So i need number of items produced till time i have opened page and numer of milliseconds remaining in current year till 31st dec at 24:00

Comment: What have you tried?  How was it deficient?

Answer (score 1):

```
  const first = new Date();
  first.setDate(1);
  first setMonth(0);
  first.setHours(0);
  first.setMinutes(0);

  const delta = Date.now() - first;

  const perMS = 4 * 10 ** 6 / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);

  console.log(delta * perMS);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the total number of milliseconds passed in the current year, you can then subtract it from total milliseconds in a year

```
var diff = new Date(Math.abs(new Date() - new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 1))).getTime();
console.log(diff);
```

Comment: Thanks, i used this script and got desired result. Thanks all who replied to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have used below script, countup script is working fine, I need 'from' and 'speed' variable.

```
$.fn.countTo = function(options) {
    // merge the default plugin settings with the custom options
    options = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults, options || {});

    // how many times to update the value, and how much to increment the value on each update
    var loops = Math.ceil(options.speed / options.refreshInterval),
        increment = (options.to - options.from) / loops;

    return $(this).each(function() {
        var _this = this,
            loopCount = 0,
            value = options.from,
            interval = setInterval(updateTimer, options.refreshInterval);

        function updateTimer() {
            value += increment;
            loopCount++;
            $(_this).html(value.toFixed(options.decimals));

            if (typeof(options.onUpdate) == 'function') {
                options.onUpdate.call(_this, value);
            }

            if (loopCount >= loops) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                value = options.to;

                if (typeof(options.onComplete) == 'function') {
                    options.onComplete.call(_this, value);
                }
            }
        }
    });
};

$.fn.countTo.defaults = {
    from: 0,  // the number the element should start at
    to: 100,  // the number the element should end at
    speed: 1000,  // how long it should take to count between the target numbers
    refreshInterval: 100,  // how often the element should be updated
    decimals: 0,  // the number of decimal places to show
    onUpdate: null,  // callback method for every time the element is updated,
    onComplete: null,  // callback method for when the element finishes updating
};

var date = new Date("2019, 1, 1");
var seconds = date.getTime() / 1000; 

var prRatePerSec = 0.12;
var prPerYear = 4000000;
var prProducedTill = Math.round(seconds * prRatePerSec);

$('.timer').countTo({
    from: 0,
    to: prPerYear,
    speed: 31540000000,
    refreshInterval: 50,
    onComplete: function (value) {
        console.debug(this);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can substract two date object with javascript.

So substract the current date with the start year date

Like

```js
var second = diffCurrentYear() / 1000;
var day = second / 60 / 60 / 24;

console.log(day)

function diffCurrentYear() {
  var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear(),
    diff = (new Date()).getTime() - (new Date(currentYear + '-01-01')).getTime()
  return diff;
}
```